# Justify buttons equal with and aligned to the sides

Tags: react-native

I need to make buttons equal width and if possible align to the edges of the container.

[image]

I've tried without success the following:

```
<View style={{flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'}>

   <View  style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Button title="Button 1"/>
   </View>

   <View  style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Button title="Button 2"/>
   </View>
</View>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by aligned to the edge ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the width, you can simply set the width of your buttons to 100%.
And if I understand correctly what you mean by aligning them to the edge, you can use `justifyContent: 'space-between'` on your container.

Ps. you might want to add some padding on the Views wrapping your buttons

You would have something like :

```
<View style={{flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'row',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'space-between'}>

  <View  style={{flex: 1}}>
    <Button title="Button 1" style={{width: "100%"}}/>
  </View>

  <View  style={{flex: 1}}>
    <Button title="Button 2" style={{width: "100%"}}/>
  </View>
</View>
```